# What would be the best approach to raise newborn humans in a generation ship without computers or previous humans?

Tags: science-based, generation-ships

So, in this scenario, humans just proven that the light-speed limit is absolute. In other words, you can't travel faster than light, even with warp drives or worm-holes. To get things worse, even with the expansion of the human civilisation through the solar system, it still is economically unfeasible to travel at any significant percentage of the speed of light.

So, trying to spread the human civilisation in a dubious panic of "the resources of the solar system are finite, send our last hope", humans started creating generation ships to colonise other systems.

However, instead of sending giant ships or conglomerates of ships with living humans inside, they decided to send frozen zygotes and DNA that would become zygotes as a system back-up.

But as it is said in the title of this question: How they would raise and teach these to-be-humans and teach them how to read and write?

Computers may last centuries if they aren't in constant active service, and even if its systems once they start receiving the solar system light on their solar panels, there still is the possibility that they might not work.

So, in a back-up system where the electronic computers don't work and the analog computers (with gears and such) also don't work due to the millennia long trip, what are the options left? I should just define these situations as a total failure, **since if these teaching devices wouldn't work the gestation devices wouldn't be working either**?

I also don't want to mess too much with genetic engineering humans to be immortals or being super humans that could understand a language by just looking at it.

Comment: How are the zygotes grow into humans and what takes care of the babies? I don't see how it is plausible without some very sophisticated machines.

Comment: You cannot. You've fundamentally disallowed native information devices of any kind by disallowing teachers, computers, and biological modification. This question is underdeveloped. If there are no pilots or computers then how does the ship even arrive? You're putting the cart before the horse. The zygotes will never make it to the destination. Even V2 rockets had more available to them and still couldn't hit their targets with much less distance to travel and those didn't have to land properly.

Comment: And the orphans raised without human contact result in emotionally stunted adults (see Romanian orphanages).

Comment: @DKNguyen "*So, in a back-up system where the electronic computers don't work and the analog computers (with gears and such) also don't work*" " should just define these situations as a total failure, since *if these teaching devices wouldn't work the gestation devices wouldn't be working either?*".

Comment: @NetoAnanias Yes. Another way to look at it is that if even gears don't work, what else does? Generation ships will need some replicating or regeneratable caretaking mechanism unless you have Clarktech.

Comment: @NetoAnanias unfortunately a question asking "the best" of anything is asking for eveyone's opinions. This site is a place to get expert answers (which have actual answers in fact). You need to please come up with your story (I can recommend the writing stack exchange for this), and then change this question to ask how plausible your solution would be. We will give expert advice on that matter easily. I have to vote to close until your story is formed, unfortunately.

Comment: @VogonPoet Armchair expert advice anyways. I neither design, manufacture, nor operate generation ships nor do I raise and educate newborns without the use of technology, myself, or other humans.

Answer (score 2):

## Sentient cats.

As you noted, you don't want to have genetically engineered humans. As such, instead, you could have uplifted cats. They are as intelligent as humans, and can do basic maintenance on key machines to ensure survival. They can be taught how to raise humans.

They can pass on this knowledge through generations, and when it is time awaken the humans and teach them all they know.

Comment: Then came the human-feline war for dominance.

Answer (score 1):

**Sophisticated genetic engineering.**

They each possess massive genomes, the equivalent of petabytes of information. This is all set to direct brain-growth from the foetus to the adult such that the connections form a complex template based on the living experiences, expertise and talents of a select cadre of individuals - scientists, artists, artisans, engineers, managers, psychologists and medical professionals. Oh, and a few astronauts just for luck.

As precedent in existing works see: [Leeloo](https://fifth-element.fandom.com/wiki/Leeloo) and her origin as [Mondoshawan](https://fifth-element.fandom.com/wiki/Mondoshawan) from Luc Besson's film [The Fifth Element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fifth_Element), or a variation: The Bene Gesserit's (and Paul's) other-memory from [Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel)).

The basics kick-in around birth, sufficient competence to perform the necessities for survival aboard the ship - which must be equipped to deal with toddler-sized hungry and ready-to-work individuals. Of course, the equipment must be height adjustable and grow as they grow. By the time puberty hits, they must be capable of making their own choices about mating/prophylaxis as any adult would (supposedly).

Comment: Ruled out by OP with "*I also don't want to mess too much with genetic engineering humans to be immortals or being super humans that could understand a language by just looking at it.*"

Comment: Damn, I missed that. Not sure there are any options left - except have a meet and greet party at the other end which does the job for them. @DKNguyen

Answer (score 0):

Why cant the tech be just as advanced? Have futuristic botmom or even a built in AI within the nurture chamber that stimulates the babies brains and gives them the right amount of nurture and help develop with skills needed to survive. Almost like a fail proof that works for 15-20years. The children will develop to the point of speaking writing and even understand computers if given proper resources and education by the AI. Sort of like Superman and his father in the fortress of solitude. His fathers personality and knowledge is engrained within the AI to respond to questions from superman correctly and fatherlike. You can do the same for an AI to raise the children.

Comment: Hi Zakaria, please read carefully through the [Tour] to familiarize yourself more with this platform. Like one of your other recent answers it seems you are asking for details more than answering the question (although in this case it could be a "frame challenge"). Please focus on answering questions until you have enough reputation to comment. Welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment: Is a thought out answer, almost walking the person with me while drawing the image. The answer is there. The questions I ask are rhetorical to the answers i'm giving. 1) why cant the tech be as advanced? if we're able to create generation ships to conquer other planets, why cant we program AI/Robots to raise the zygote into adults lol. 2) I gave a reference to superman and his father that is dead but an AI he created with he same characteristics to help superman when difficult situations/questions arose in his life. I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

If tech won't work, have uplifted lifeforms do maintenance and teaching duties. A fellow commenter, Nepene Nep, proposed sentient cats above, but uplifted rats or other species who could theoretically thrive on a long space voyage would work.